# Actionscript 3: assigning variable name to XML data to populate text fields

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, variables

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <driverone>Mario Andretti</driverone>
    <drivertwo>Luigi Andretti</drivertwo>
</root>
```

Super simple - all I have are two names, driverone and drivertwo.

And here's my ActionScript 3:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.controls.Label;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

stop();

var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("bulkfuel.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.driverone);
    trace(myXML.drivertwo);
}

//define variable from XML data
var firstDriver:String = String(myXML.@driverone);
var coDriver:String= String(myXML.@drivertwo);

//populate text fields with variables
DriverOne_txt.text=String(firstDriver);
DriverTwo_txt.text=String(coDriver);
```

Everything works down to the trace function. For some reason, and I know it's stupidly simple but I just can't seem to find it, I can't get these names to load into the text fields.

Answer (score 1):

`@` - is an attribute.
Use just `myXML.driverone`.

Comment: And seems like OP also needs to put the last lines in to the `processXML` handler too..